# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'todoText' of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

Working on the Javascript objects and functions. Facing issue with it.

```
  var todoList = {
      todo:[],
      displayTodo:function(){
        console.log('My Todo:',this.todo); 
      },
      addTodo:function(todoText){
        this.todo.push({
          todoText:todoText,
          complete:false
        });
        this.displayTodo();
      },
      changeTodo:function(posi,newTodo){
        //this.todo[posi] = newTodo; 
        this.todo[posi].todoText=newTodo;
        this.displayTodo();
      },
      toggleComplte:function(posi){
        var todo = this.todo[posi];
        todo.complete = !todo.complete;
        this.displayTodo();
      }
    }

    todoList.addTodo('Item1');
    todoList.toggleComplte(0);
```

Error I got when running.

```
VM1196:16 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'todoText' of undefined
    at Object.changeTodo (<anonymous>:16:29)
    at <anonymous>:21:10
```

Can some one suggest what is the error ?

Comment: Looks like your 'this.todo[posi]' is returning an undefined value in the changeTodo function. Theres no example above of where you call the function changeTodo so would need more of an example to help further.

Comment: Probably no todos exist, ergo accessing todo #0 will fail because `this.todo[0]` is undefined (i.e. you effectively do `undefined.todoText = ...` at the end, and this results in the error you got). You would by the way easily see that if you had used a debugger. Check out this tutorial: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/

Comment: @AidanGee yes it is. Initially I had added a value using addTodo function, just to make sure I have some value to toggle. I am editing last lines in the program and then check.

Comment: @CherryDT try the code now. Initially there was not todo so ideally there was a problem. Not I have added a Todo using addTodo, but the same problem

Comment: I see you edited your post. However now your code works, so we can't help you finding a problem which doesn't exist in the code you posted :) https://db.tt/tMs8QrXoKK

Comment: Actually, `changeTodo` (in which you got the error) is never called in your example.

Comment: @CherryDT actually now I got the problem. Ideally the addtodo method was not called. Now actually I understood the problem. Thanks Guys !

Comment: @CherryDT SInce I am new to the JS, can u help me with dev debugger you have shared ?

Answer (score 1):

with your current changes you code is working fine, i am not seeing any console error

```js
  var todoList = {
      todo:[],
      displayTodo:function(){
        console.log('My Todo:',this.todo); 
      },
      addTodo:function(todoText){
        this.todo.push({
          todoText:todoText,
          complete:false
        });
        this.displayTodo();
      },
      changeTodo:function(posi,newTodo){
        //this.todo[posi] = newTodo; 
        this.todo[posi].todoText=newTodo;
        this.displayTodo();
      },
      toggleComplte:function(posi){
        var todo = this.todo[posi];
        todo.complete = !todo.complete;
        this.displayTodo();
      }
    }

    todoList.addTodo('Item1');
    todoList.toggleComplte(0);
```